# Drag and drop pure HTML with jQuery UI Draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

**How can I drag HTML content over to a "canvas"?**

I would like to have a simple looking list of buttons (draggable items), where I can drag and drop one item.

I want a simple list of buttons, but when dragged and dropped onto the "canvas" I want it to populate different HTML for each button.

I have seen somebody use a parameter in the draggable item, like "data-insert-html". In here I have seen people use basic HTML, or a path to a html file they want dropped into the .mywrapper.

I have tried different ways. This is most close, but still some miles from where I want to be:

```
<div class="draggable"  data-insert-html='<h1>Some HTML</h1>'>
My button text
</div>
<div class="draggable"  data-insert-html='<p>Some other content</p>'>
My button #2 text
</div>
```

The JS:

I have found that I can use this to get the data:

```
var insertingHTML = $(this).attr('data-insert-html');
```

But have not found a good way to drop that "insertingHTML" into the canvas in stead of the DIV's content.

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable({
      connectToSortable: ".mywrapper",
      helper: "clone",
       helper: function(event) {
            return "<div class='custom-helper'>Add '" + $(this).context.innerHTML + "' by letting it go on the yellow field.</div>";

        },
        // I have tried to use the STOP event. But the problem with it is that I can only drag one item ONCE to the canvas. I want infinite. 
        stop: function() {

        // This gets the correct data from the draggable DIV
        var insertingHTML = $(this).attr('data-insert-html');

         // BUT then I am lost. How do I add this to where the marker is?
        event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("Text",insertingHTML);
        // test ended
      },
      revert: "invalid",
    });
    $().disableSelection();
```

Here is a fiddle to play with:
http://jsfiddle.net/Preben/pcawje7u/8/

Can you help me fix my code?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your new text to the dragged item by using the function below.
It adds every dragged item the property it holds with it. `data-insert-html`

```
stop: function() {
        $('.mywrapper [data-insert-html]').each(function(){
          $(this).html($(this).attr('data-insert-html'));
        });
      },
```

Edit: I forgat to target only the dragged area. I fixed my code.

Comment: Wrong link. I did some strange here. Give me a minute :-)

Comment: fixed my comment, try it please.

Comment: Excellent! Works :-)